# Javascript regex search/replace is skipping over matches

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying the following in both FF and Chrome

```
' 1 2 3 4 5 6 '.replace(/([\s()])(\d+)([\s()])/g, '$1[num $2]$3');
```

The result I'm expecting:

```
" [num 1] [num 2] [num 3] [num 4] [num 5] [num 6] "
```

The result I'm getting (both browsers):

```
" [num 1] 2 [num 3] 4 [num 5] 6 "
```

Even simplifying gives the same result:

```
' 1 2 3 4 5 6 '.replace(/\s(\d+)\s/g, ' [num $1] ');
```

Any ideas what's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your `\s`s are consuming characters.  Regular expression multiple matches run forward to prevent infinite loops.  So after the first match you're already right before the 2, but there's no spaces to match, so it ignores it.

What you're going to want to do is either make your matches non-consuming using lookaheads, or use `\b` which is a zero-width match for a word boundary.

```
' 1 2 3 4 5 6 '.replace(/([\s()])(\d+)(?=[\s()])/g, '$1[num $2]')
```

This should work for you.

Comment: Your explanation is great, and I understand now. The problem is that JS doesn't support zero-width lookbehind assertions, and `\b` is too broad, I really need either whitespace or parens to match before/after the number.

Answer (score 1):

Moved answer from comment + added positive lookahead:

```
' 1 2 3 4 5 6 '.replace(/(\s)(\d+)(?=\s)/g, '$1[num $2]');
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
' 1 2 3 4 5 6 '.replace(/(\d+)/g, '[num $1]');
```